# Need help in setting the SSL in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

I have purchased SSL from Godaddy and my website is hosted in AWS. I want to   set up the SSL on AWS. I tied to use the Certificate Manager to import the certificate. It asked me 3 things :

**Certificate body*** -- Here I enetered the .CRT file content which I got from Godaddy

**Certificate private key*** -- Here I am still confused what need to be entered. Please help me with this

**Certificate chain** -- Here I entered the sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt code .

Please help me enable the SSL in AWS . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you try and open the main certificate in any editor you will see :

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Base64–encoded private key
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

This needs to be imported there, you can refer to this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-format.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thansk for your response.When you say main certificate , you mean "CRT" file provided by Godaddy ?

Comment: yes that is it, you will see begin RSA private key section

Comment: But in my crt it start with  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- CERTIFICATE ENGRYPTED CODE IS HERE-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: it might be in middle not starting of the file and explore all files you got not just one.